# How can I filter discussions to newer instead of from years in the past?

Tags: support

Since I am the kind of person to find answers and share with others, how can I filter out discussions that are no longer relevant like from 2012, when it is 2018? I have found that the past versions of programs that people are requesting assistance with are no longer supported as the newer environments don't even allow the dependencies to be installed.

I find solutions to problems all the time. I currently work maintaining Data Centers and have access to several issues and solutions daily. I also use Linux and VMware. I have tried various distros and love a good challenge. Most problems have already been solved by someone else, but not everyone is willing to go and find them. Currently I am teaching myself Python as I never want to stop learning.

Comment: Just because a Q/A is from 2012 or even earlier does not mean it is out of date. Many aspects of configuration files in Ubuntu have been the same since 2004

Answer (score 8):

As noted in https://askubuntu.com/help/searching you can filter on dates. Filters for dates are

> **created:** to specify when the posts were created last
>   **lastactive:** for posts active in a specified time period

Relative dates:

**1y**, **1m**, and **1d** are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday" - e.g., if today is April 15, **created:1m** searches posts created between March 1 and March 31. (You can substitute any number for 1 to look back that many years, months, or days.)

Relative dates in a range (**1y..**) look back to the same date in the previous period - e.g., if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use **lastactive:3m..** On April 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can close the range as well: **lastactive:3m..1m**.

The link above also shows how to use absolute dates, but it look like relative dates would be more useful to you.